# switch on a long wire end causing microcontroller to shutdown

Tags: microcontroller, pic, switches, relay, wiring

i've a push button connected to micro-controller using a 100m 18ga wire that cause the micro-controller to shutdown after few times of working properly

the circuit is fully functional with a short wire, i use 5v, both CN2/3 has lamp/bell load and sw1 wire is the 100m wire

[image]

Comment: Add a flyback diode on the circuit board across the wires to SW1.  Use caution adding capacitors across the switch, you can make an LC tank that way.  The gold standard, if you are not sure, is to use an opto-isolator.

Answer (score 6):

At 100 meters of 18awg cable, i think it the wire starts to have enough inductance to have the system start experiencing inductive kick backs when the switch opens up. A small capacitor across the SW1 can be an effective snubber. Also add some decoupling capacitors across V+ and V- of your MCU.

Answer (score 1):

Add some series resistors to the PIC inputs (pins 4 and 5)- something like 10K is fine.

And do as @Andrew says and make sure you have adequate bypass capacitors on the chip (something like 0.1uF ceramic in parallel with 10uF electrolytic is good- the 0.1uF close to the micro - within 5-10mm).

I doubt putting anything across the switch will make any positive improvement.

Comment: i am kinda lost here so bear with me for a moment, the wire is twisted and long which is why it's behaving like a solenoid and doing kickbacks (was trying to simulate it and got like 2k volts that clear over few hundred ms) so how a resistor on pin 4 and 5 will fix it, and for the kickback fix i saw it across/parallel to the solenoid to kill the kickbacks but the answer i got was to put it across(which i duno series or parallel) with the switch, @Spehro Pefhany

Comment: A series resistor will limit the current into the PIC chip inputs and should prevent it  from getting upset. Right now the inputs are probably absorbing the energy through the input protection networks.